# Unable to see IIS on my pc after installation

Tags: windows-7, iis-7.5

I have downloaded IIS 7.5 from following url http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038 and installed on Windows 7 Home Basic. The installation was successful. Even though I'm unable to see IIS in my start menu. When I typed `inetmgr` in run and clicked on OK, it's showing an error message.
I typed `iisreset` in command prompt. It's restarting the IIS. When I tried to install IIS from Windows Platform Installer, it's showing IIS as installed on my PC. But, I'm unable to see the IIS.
Please help me out.

Answer (score -1):

- In the Control Panel, click Programs.
- Click Turn Windows features on or off.
- You may receive the Windows Security warning. Click Allow to continue. The Windows Features dialog box is displayed.
- Expand Internet Information Services. Additional categories of IIS features are displayed. Select Internet Information Services to choose the default features for installation.
- Expand the additional categories displayed, and select any additional features you want to install, such as Web Management Tools.
- If you are installing IIS for evaluation purposes, you may want to select additional features to install. Select the check boxes for all IIS features you want to install, and then click OK to start installation.
- The progress indicator appears.
- IIS is now installed with a default configuration on Windows Vista or Windows
- Next, you can use Internet Information Services Manager to manage and configure IIS. To open IIS Manager, click Start, type inetmgr in the Search Programs and Files box, and then press ENTER.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Sorry, I forgot to mention. I followed the above process  before installing IIS 7.5. That did not worked for me.

Comment: Have you checked in:  control panel -> system and security -> administrative tools. If you have  IIS manager ?

Comment: Yes. I just checked, It's not there in administrative tool. In article I found that IIS 7.0 can not be installed on Windows7 Home Basic. In another article I found that IIS 7.5 can be installed on Windows 7 Home Basic.

Comment: True, IIS do not function on that version of Windows 7. IIS necessarily what you want? You can use a virtual machine as freeebsd virtualbox.  And local webserver configured for testing.